# How to use value of variable from one job to another

Tags: circleci, circleci-workflows

**Objective:** Trying to pass one step variable in Job A to Job B in CircleCI or if possible to create an environment variable programmatically to a CircleCI context

**What I have done so far:**

I have config like below, but as part of step, I need to store one string value ($key in below snippet) in step and use it in next job.

But I read documentation that each "run" runs on own shell and, I saw export to bash as a work around, but I am using windows executor… so it won't be option

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  self-hosted-agent-test:
    machine: true
    resource_class: xxxxxxx/devops-self-hosted-agent
    
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:           
          command: az login --service-principal -u $xxxxxx -p $xxxxx --tenant $xxxx
      - run:           
          command: az group create --location $xxxxx --name $xxxxxxxx
      - run:           
          command: az storage account create --name $xxxxxxxx --resource-group $xxxxxxx --location $xxxxx --sku Standard_LRS
      - run:          
          command: az storage container create --name xxxxxx --account-name $xxxxxxxx
      - run:          
          command: Connect-AzAccount --service-principal -u $xxx -p $xxx --tenant $xxxx
      - run: 
          shell: powershell.exe
          command: $key=(Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $xxxxxxxxx -AccountName $xxxxxxx)[0].Value

  self-hosted-agent-test1:
    machine: true
    resource_class: xxxxxxx/devops-self-hosted-agent    
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: 
          name: Storage key persistance check
          command: Write-Host $key   
workflows:
  my-workflow:
    jobs:
      - self-hosted-agent-test:
          context:
            - abcd
      - self-hosted-agent-test1
```

Can you suggest how to achieve this or how to create environment variable during build (not through UI manually with this $key so that I refer to that in next job in workflow

Update:

I have used below but getting parsing error:

```
  name: "Create Context"
  command:
    curl --request POST \
    --url https://circleci.com/api/v2/context \
    --header 'authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
    --header 'content-type:' 'application/json' \
    --data '{"name":"string","owner":{"id":"string","type":"organization"}}'
```

Error:

```
Unable to parse YAML
mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'string', line 23, column 36:
                --header 'authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CircleCI API v2: https://circleci.com/docs/api/v2/#operation/addEnvironmentVariableToContext

Comment: I have followed that document. updated original post with my curl statement, but I am getting parsing error

Comment: The endpoint you mentioned above is to create a context, rather than add an environment variable to an existing context, as I suggested.

If you really want to take that route, you'll need to:
1. Make the appropriate call to the "Create a context" endpoint (i.e, specify an actual name for the context and valid owner ID, instead of the `string` placeholders
2. Extract the ID of the thus created context from the API response, and the use it with the "Add or update an environment variable" endpoint.

Comment: An easier approach is to:
1. Manually create a context in the UI and note its ID
2. Use that ID in your call to the "Add or update an environment variable" endpoint.

Comment: Hi I am able to manage to create context with api and pass it to a variable using json jq and used in creating variable because we are doing automated creation of context and pass id to next  curl to add variables.. thank you very much for suggestions